# Access to SD card denied - UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, sd-card, access-denied

Using UWP I'm trying to access an SD card.  I'm on Windows 10.  I've gone into Package.appxmanifest ...

under Capabilities, I've checked Removable Storage

under Declarations, I've added a File Type Assocation.  Name is "txt", File Type is ".txt".  The relevant portion ...

```
  <Extensions>
    <uap:Extension Category="windows.fileTypeAssociation">
      <uap:FileTypeAssociation Name="txt">
        <uap:DisplayName>text</uap:DisplayName>
        <uap:SupportedFileTypes>
          <uap:FileType>.txt</uap:FileType>
        </uap:SupportedFileTypes>
      </uap:FileTypeAssociation>
    </uap:Extension>
  </Extensions>
```

My code to create a text file ...

```
    string fileName = @"D:\test.txt";

    using (FileStream fs = File.Create(fileName))
    {   
        Byte[] text = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes("testing");
        fs.Write(text, 0, text.Length);
    }
```

The result every time, "Access to the path 'D:\text.txt' is denied"

I am able to manually create and copy files to this directory.  So, why can I not create a file using UWP?  I've followed all the rules.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use `File.Create()` to access files in limited UWP apps. You need to use the functionality in the `Windows.Storage` namespace.

```
private async void Test()
{
    string filePath = @"D:\";
    string fileName = @"Test.txt";

    // get StorageFile object
    StorageFolder folder = await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(filePath);
    StorageFile file = await folder.CreateFileAsync(fileName, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

    // Open Stream and Write content
    using (Stream stream = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
    {
        Byte[] text = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes("testing");
        await stream.WriteAsync(text, 0, text.Length);
    }
}
```

Comment: That did it.  However, I'm also trying to create - which works using your method - and then perform operations on a database file.  When I check for File.Exists(file), it returns false.  If I try to connect to the database, new SQLiteConnection("data source=" + DatabaseFile), I get hung in an "Access is denied" loop.  Any tips on this?

Comment: You cannot use `File.Exists()`, you cannot use any of the traditional functionality for accessing the file system. Only functionality inside the `Windows.Storage` namespace. For example, for checking whether a file exists, use for example `StorageFolder.TryGetItemAsync()`.

Comment: For using SQLite inside an UWP application, you must make sure that you use the correct SQLite package from Microsoft. Have you setup the application exactly as described in https://learn.microsoft.com/en/windows/uwp/data-access/sqlite-databases

Comment: Okay, I will check out that link.  Thanks for the help.  I was stuck for quite a while, so I appreciate it.